# Django: How to drop default sqlite database?

Tags: django, sqlite

I need to drop my database since I want to use a customized user model in my project. I've used the default database that is used when following the [django introduction tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/). I connect to the database through the terminal with `python manage.py dbshell`. Then, I locate the database:

```
sqlite> .databases
main: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/mydatabase
```

And I proceed to delete the database:

```
$ rm /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/mydatabase
$ rm /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/mydatabase
rm: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/mydatabase: No such file or directory
```

But the database still shows up in the database connection:

```
sqlite> .databases
main: /Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/workout/mydatabase
```

And when I try to detach, I get an error:

```
sqlite> detach database main;
Error: cannot detach database main
```

Is this a problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to delete it while you have it open in sqlite? Quit first, then delete it.

Comment: Quit what and how? I think I need to be connected to sqlite in order to run commands such as `DETACH`.

Comment: But why do you think you need to run DETACH? Once you've deleted the database, it's gone.

Comment: But why, then, does main still show up when I type `.databases` and points to the file which I've already deleted? Is it always there per default?

Comment: Because you've still got the sqlite console open, and presumably it doesn't refresh its connections during the session. But there is no reason to have that open; as I said, you should quit that console before deleting the file.

Comment: Note of course that when you then subsequently run `dbshell` again, it will recreate that file, *but that's fine*.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Daniel.